# What is this OST for Episode 4 of Rurouni Kenshin / Samurai X?

Tags: music, rurouni-kenshin

The OST starts playing on Episode 4 as Sanosuke (Zanza) catches the waitress from her fall and starts trash-talking the drunk democrats.

I haven't been able to find it in the OSTs myself. It seems Sano has other OSTs considered as his 'theme', so it has been difficult to track down.

Here's a YouTube video of this scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdSArCFcRTc

Although I couldn't find the original audio, this Spanish version does use the same music.

Comment: Can you give us a youtube link for the scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minagoroshi no Jungle -Master Mix- from the Director's Unreleased Collection or from the 4th soundtrack volume